# Retrieve result query nodejs result

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, request

I would like to be able to make my request and retrieve the result in a variable outside the request.

```
request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(body);
});
```

I've already tried it with `return` but the result remains the same : `undefined`

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a callback you need to assign, not return, e.g.

```
let myBody;
request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
 if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(body);
    myBody = body;
});
```

To be clear - since this is inside a callback, the request will likely end when the callback is executed. If you want to do some processing the most straightforward way is to call the functions inside the callback e.g.:

```
request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
 if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(body);
    res1 = callFunctionOneHere(body);
    res2 = callFunctionTwoHere(body);
    // and so on
});
```

Comment: Thank you but the value outside the request does not display the result.